# How to stop auto renewal in an in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to know if there is a way to stop auto-renewal of my app's subscription from within my app. Also, is there any way to get the subscription end date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to stop auto-renewal programatically.
For calculating end date, you have to know how long the subscription duration is and then add it to purchase_date field that you get from StoreKit.

Comment: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/                                                           Blog + Open Source Code here

Comment: is it possible to take the user to his app store settings page from where he can cancel my app's auto renewal ??

Comment: I don't think so. At least as of iOS 5, there is no obvious way.